# How to open wechat and open link in it from browser mobile

Tags: html, wechat

I use this code to open wechat from chrome browser:

```
<a href="weixin://">
    <button>Open wechat</button>
</a>
```

I try to use weixin://dl/businessWebview/link/url=www.google.com to open link google.com. But when open in wechat, there is an error "invalid_source". What is the best way to do it?

Comment: try weixin://dl/businessWebview/link/?url=google.com

Comment: I try to use other link, but it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been deprecated for several years now - there is no way to reliably achieve this functionality at the time of writing.